# Can't get data out of indexedDB

Tags: javascript, indexeddb

Here's the function I'm trying to call:

```
function restoreCurrent() {
    var tzact = db.transaction(['Picture'],"readonly").objectStore("Picture").get(2);
    tzact.onerror = function(event) {
        alert ("Failed to retrieve the data.");
    }
    tzact.onsuccess = function(event) {
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML += "Transaction success.<br />";
    }
}
window.onload = function() {
    restoreCurrent();
}
```

As you can see, it should output something on either a success or an error.  In fact it doesn't output anything.  I had further code after this in the .onsuccess function, but nothing gets executed.  And the line where it stops working is the database call, I've tested that much.
For the record, both this line of code when I created the database

```
var tzact = db.transaction(['Picture'], "readwrite").objectStore("Picture").add({id : 2, pictureData : working});
```

and this line when I try and update that particular record

```
var tzact = db.transaction(['Picture'], "readwrite").objectStore("Picture").put({id : 2, pictureData : working});
```

seemed to execute OK -- or at least, the functions they were embedded in went on to output success messages.  Without being able to extract any data it's hard to be sure.

EDIT: Figured it out myself.  The answer is that I had to put this into each function:

```
var request = window.indexedDB.open("[database name]",5);
request.onerror = function() {
    alert ("Failed to open the database.");
}
request.onsuccess = function() {
    var db = request.result;
    var tzact = db.transaction(['Picture'],"readonly").objectStore("Picture").get(2); // or "readwrite" and .put(2), as the case might be
    tzact.onerror=function() {
        alert ("Data transaction failed.");
    }
    tzact.onsuccess=function() {
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML += "Data transaction successful.<br />";
        if (tzact.result) {
            var working = tzact.result.pictureData;
            // the rest of the function goes here
        } else {
            alert ("No data received.");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you yet checked `window.onload`? Is it triggered properly?

Comment: When I put `alert("ping");` as the first line in the function, it alerts "ping", so yes.  When I put it after the `var tzact = //etc` line, it does nothing.

Comment: Using F12 tools, any error messages?

Comment: Yes: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'transaction' of undefined`  Which brings me a _little_ closer to understanding, but (a) `db` is defined earlier on in the code and my other functions can access it just fine, and (b) I did earlier try explicitly defining it within the function and it didn't work then.

Comment: So I tried explicitly defining `var db = window.indexedDB.open("` _[databasename]_ `",5).result;` and now I'm getting a different console error message: `Uncaught DOMException: Failed to read the 'result' property from 'IDBRequest': The request has not finished.`

Comment: I don't know what that means or what to do about it.  Any help?

Comment: @DanielCopeland It's because you're handling it wrongly. You need to listen to event `onsuccess` of IDBRequest to get the actual db connection. Please read this document for more details about opening connections to IndexedDB.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/IDBFactory/open

Comment: You need to learn about asynchronous programming before using indexedDB. All of your errors so far indicate you do not understand this part. Start there.

Comment: I'm trying to learn.  That's what I'm here for.  I've found comprehensive and comprehensible guides for everything else on w3schools, but they don't have anything on indexedDB.  The developer documentation such as @Lewis just linked me to, thank you, assumes the user already knows how it all works and just needs the method names.  Such tutorials as I've found skim over these issues and are also written in clumsy English, which doesn't help.  I have been trying to figure them out for over a week.